# R function for returning multiplication result of a function

Tags: r

appreciate your guidance as im new to R programme. basically i've created a function to check whether the value is even or odd.

i wish to create a new result column whereby 'even' results in the original value * 2, and 'odd' results in the original value - 5.

not sure where i've gone wrong with the second part of the code but i am trying to figure out where can i include my 'check' column in the second function to specify it should be checked for even or odd.

i only learnt about ifelse(check(df$check) but it doesnt seem to work in my instance.
much appreciated!

```
## print 'odd' or 'even' results in df

check = function(df,col){
  df['check'] =
     ifelse(df[,col] %% 2 ==0, 'even', 'odd')
     return(df)
}

# multiplication and subtraction for odd_even results
checkresult = function(df,col){
  df['res'] = 
    ifelse(check(df) == 'even', df[,col] * 2, df[,col]-5)
  return(df)
}

checkresult(df)
```

Comment: Your `check` function requires two arguments for a start, and you have only supplied one. Furthermore, the `check` function returns a dataframe, rendering `check(df) == 'even'` to be `df == 'even'`, which will not evaluate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @philiptomk i changed it to but got NA results for my 'res' column


`# multiplication and subtraction for odd_even results
checkresult = function(df,col){
  df['res'] = 
    ifelse(check(df$result) == 'even', df[,col] * 2, df[,col]-5)
  return(df)
}`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is by **not** implementing a new function, just use `ifelse()` as it was intended:

```r
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:15, size = 100, replace = T))
df$res <- ifelse(df$x %% 2 == 0, df$x * 2, df$x  - 5)
df |> head()
#>    x res
#> 1 10  20
#> 2  7   2
#> 3  6  12
#> 4  3  -2
#> 5  9   4
#> 6 10  20
```

If you need to implement a function that returns a dataframe:

```r
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:15, size = 100, replace = T))

my_func <- function(dframe, column){
  vec <- dframe[,column]
  dframe$res <- ifelse(vec %% 2 == 0, vec * 2, vec - 5)
  return(dframe)
}

my_func(df, "x") |> head()
#>    x res
#> 1 10  20
#> 2  7   2
#> 3  6  12
#> 4  3  -2
#> 5  9   4
#> 6 10  20
```

#### Edit 1

If you want the parity of the number, one extra line is required:

```r
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:15, size = 100, replace = T))

my_func <- function(dframe, column){
  vec <- dframe[,column]
  dframe$parity <- ifelse(vec %% 2 == 0, "EVEN", "ODD")
  dframe$res <- ifelse(vec %% 2 == 0, vec * 2, vec - 5)
  return(dframe)
}

my_func(df, "x") |> head()
#>    x parity res
#> 1 10   EVEN  20
#> 2  7    ODD   2
#> 3  6   EVEN  12
#> 4  3    ODD  -2
#> 5  9    ODD   4
#> 6 10   EVEN  20
```

Comment: thanks! I am trying to create a function that prints both the odd/even results as well as the intended res column. did i get anything wrong with the code?

`my_func = function(df,col){
  vec = df[,col]
  df['check'] = ifelse (vec %% 2 == 0, 'even' , 'odd'){
  df['res'] = ifelse (df$coltest == 'even', vec * 2. vec - 5)
  }
  return(df)
  }`

Comment: got it! appreciate it